# Django CMS: Update from aldryn-blog to aldryn-newsblog

Tags: python, django, django-cms, data-migration, divio

#### The Django CMS app [Aldryn blog is deprecated since 2015](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-blog), and replaced by [Aldryn newsblog](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog).

**What is the optimal way to update from aldryn-blog to aldryn-newsblog (Django 1.6.11 compatible)? The ultimate goal is to be able to update our Django system from 1.6.1x to 1.7.y**

- How can aldryn-blog entries be migrated to aldryn-newsblog?
- How can aldryn-newsblog leads be made HTML compatible?
- What is the best succession of updates to go from Django 1.6.x to Django 1.7.y and migrating from aldryn-blog to aldryn-newsblog?

#### Details of our current setup

**requirements.txt**:

```
--extra-index-url https://divio:wlkdjeorijlerf@pkg.divio.ch/simple/
--extra-index-url https://devpi.divio.ch/divio/all/+simple/
aldryn-apphooks-config==0.2.7
aldryn-blog==0.4.6
aldryn-boilerplates==0.7.4
aldryn-categories==1.0.2
aldryn-common==0.1.4
aldryn-faq==1.0.5
aldryn-gallery==0.2.1
aldryn-newsblog==1.2.1
aldryn-people==1.2.0
aldryn-reversion==1.0.8
aldryn-search==0.2.11
aldryn-translation-tools==0.2.1
argparse==1.2.1
cmsplugin-plaintext-djangocms3==0.2.1
dill==0.2.4
Django==1.6.11
django-admin-sortable==2.0.15
django-admin-sortable2==0.6.3
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-appdata==0.1.5
django-ckeditor==4.4.7
django-classy-tags==0.7.2
django-cms==3.0.15
django-countries==3.3
django-crispy-forms==1.5.1
django-filer==1.2.0
django-haystack==2.4.1
django-hvad==1.5.0
django-meta==0.3.1
django-meta-mixin==0.2.1
django-mptt==0.6.1
django-parler==1.6.2
django-phonenumber-field==1.1.0
django-polymorphic==0.8.1
django-reversion==1.8.4
django-sekizai==0.9.0
Django-Select2==4.3.1
django-sortedm2m==1.0.2
django-spurl==0.6.4
django-standard-form==1.1.4
django-taggit==0.11.2
django-treebeard==4.0
djangocms-admin-style==1.1.0
djangocms-column==1.4
djangocms-file==0.0.2
djangocms-flash==0.0.3
djangocms-googlemap==0.1.0
djangocms-inherit==0.0.2
djangocms-installer==0.5.4
djangocms-link==1.4.0
djangocms-picture==0.0.4
djangocms-snippet==1.5
djangocms-style==1.4
djangocms-teaser==0.0.2
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.3.0
djangocms-video==0.0.2
factory-boy==2.5.2
fake-factory==0.5.3
html5lib==0.9999999
lockfile==0.10.2
mock==1.3.0
pandas==0.16.2
phonenumbers==7.3.1
phonenumberslite==7.3.1
Pillow==2.5.3
psycopg2==2.6.1
pytz==2014.7
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

**Are the Aldryn blog templates overridden in your project?**

Yes, but only superficially. Currently, we did already delete Aldryn blog templates, but can revert this step. If needed to answer my Q, I'd happily make these templates available.

**Are there custom extensions to Aldryn blog on your project?**

No.

**Are the blog articles currently searchable? (haystack)**

`django-haystack` is installed, but we are not currently using this functionality.

**Are you using any of the plugins provided by Aldryn blog? Like Authors or Tags?**

Aldryn blog posts are tagged and have authors, but we are not using the Tags or BlogAuthors Plugins' extra functionalities.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

here's my answers to some of your questions:

**How can aldryn-newsblog leads be made HTML compatible?**

Yes, Aldryn newsblog uses djangocms-text-ckeditor's `HTMLField`

**How can aldryn-blog entries be migrated to aldryn-newsblog?**

Very carefully :) Kidding...

First of, the only way to do this migration is to stay on 1.6 during the whole process.
Meaning, don't upgrade to Django >= 1.7 until this migration is fully done.

That said, in order to provide you with as much info as possible,
please post exact versions for the following packages (or pip freeze):

- Django
- django CMS
- django taggit
- Aldryn Blog
- Aldryn News & Blog (is it already installed?)
- Aldryn Categories (is it already installed?)
- django-hvad
- djangocms-text-ckeditor

Also, here's some questions:

Are the Aldryn blog templates overridden in your project?

Are there custom extensions to Aldryn blog on your project?

Are the blog articles currently searchable? (haystack)

**EDIT v1**

The way I do these kinds of migrations is to write multiple django management commands, usually one "main" command that will call the others.

By doing this I can iterate faster locally and when ready (after lots of testing) run the command directly on prod (after upgrading necessary dependencies).

I **highly** recommend using [stellar](https://github.com/fastmonkeys/stellar) for quick database snapshots during local development of the migration. Allows you to snapshot and restore db instantly and is quite easy to setup.

Here's a sample of such main command:

```
from django.core.management import call_command, CommandError
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.db import connection

from south.db import db

from cms.models import Page


class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    can_import_settings = True

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        self.stdout.write("Running migrations.\n")

        # Migrate newsblog up to 0013
        call_command('migrate', 'aldryn_newsblog', '0013')

        # Now fake migration 0014 because we don't want the default
        # app config since we'll create it in a later step
        call_command('migrate', 'aldryn_newsblog', '0014', fake=True)
        # Now migrate all the way to 0027 because we need to fake 0028
        call_command('migrate', 'aldryn_newsblog', '0027')
        # This migration has unfortunate side effects when Aldryn blog
        # is installed in the system.
        # It's ok to fake it because is just a data migration
        call_command('migrate', 'aldryn_newsblog', '0028', fake=True)
        # Move to 0035 because we need to fake 0036
        call_command('migrate', 'aldryn_newsblog', '0035')
        # Because we're not using default apphook config, fake 0036
        call_command('migrate', 'aldryn_newsblog', '0036', fake=True)

        # Proceed with all migrations
        call_command('migrate')

        self.stdout.write('Setting up blog page.\n')
        call_command('setup_blog_page')

        self.stdout.write('Migrating Aldryn Blog to Aldryn News & Blog.\n')
        call_command('migrate_blog_to_newsblog')
```

Now, you need the `setup_blog_page` and `migrate_blog_to_newsblog` commands.
Before providing them I have another question:

**Are you using any of the plugins provided by Aldryn blog? Like Authors or Tags?**